# plot the filling evolution of the mariadb database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, request, mariadb

I have a `maria db` database which increases by 15 GB in 2 years, but lately it has increased by 23 GB in one month! how can i know the problem? is that there's trackers which traces the evolution of the basic filling without making selects in each database table? I executed the following request:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myshema'
order by Data_length desc ;
```

I know the size of each table but not the evolution of the filling ?

have you an idea of how to do this diagnostic?

Answer (score 0):

There is no history (evolution).

Another clue would be `Data_free` in the same place.  A huge value there *may* indicate some action that allocated space, then freed it, but failed to give it back to the OS.

What is the value of `innodb_file_per_table`?

How big is the file `ibdata1`?

Soerch for that setting and file for further discussion of what might have happened, and what it takes to regain the space (if it were a one-time event).

You seem to have only a single datapoint indicating 23GB/month.  Check again in a a week.  It if is continually growing at a faster rate, then you will need to look at code touching the naughty table.  Again, decide which is growing:  `Data_length`, `Index_length`, or `Data_free`.

If you need more assistance, come back with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main queries involving the table.

Comment: innodb_file_per_table ON
innodb_data_file_path ibdata1:10M:autoextend